Find and Update Specific Field in all Data Extension
I want to find where a specific field is used searching in all Data Extension, after that we need to update the field in the data extensions found with a new field.
For the first part I have this script and all is working, but I was not able to do the second part.
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1");
try{
  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var cols = ["Name","CustomerKey","FieldType","IsPrimaryKey", "MaxLength"];
  var filter = {
    Property: "Name",
    SimpleOperator: "like",
    Value: "Crawlers"
  };
  var res = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionField", cols, filter);

  var arraydes = {};
  var fields = [];
  for (i = 0; i < res.Results.length; i++) {
    var dekey = res.Results[i].CustomerKey.match(/\[.*\]\.{1}/gi);
    var stringkey = dekey[0].substring(1,dekey[0].length - 2);
    arraydes[stringkey] = 1;
    res.Results[i].DEKey = stringkey;
    fields.push(res.Results[i]);
  }
  
  var dedetails = {};
  for (var key in arraydes) {
    var cols = ["Name","CustomerKey","CategoryID"];
    var filter = {
      Property: "CustomerKey",
      SimpleOperator: "equals",
      Value: key
    };
    var resb = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter);
    dedetails[key] = {Name: resb.Results[0].Name, CategoryID: resb.Results[0].CategoryID};
  };

  var finaldata = [];
  for (a = 0; a < fields.length; a++) {
    finaldata.push({CustomerKey: fields[a].CustomerKey, Name: fields[a].Name, FieldType: fields[a].FieldType, MaxLength: fields[a].MaxLength, IsPrimaryKey: fields[a].IsPrimaryKey, DataExtensionName: dedetails[fields[a].DEKey].Name, DataExtensionCategoryID: dedetails[fields[a].DEKey].CategoryID});
  }
  
  Write("<table border=1>");
  Write("<tr><th>CustomerKey</th><th>Name</th><th>FieldType</th><th>MaxLength</th><th>DataExtension</th><th>CategoryID</th></tr>");
  for (b = 0; b < finaldata.length; b++) {
   Write("<tr><td>"+finaldata[b].CustomerKey+"</td><td>"+finaldata[b].Name+"</td><td>"+finaldata[b].FieldType+"</td><td>"+finaldata[b].MaxLength+"</td><td>"+finaldata[b].DataExtensionName+"</td><td>"+finaldata[b].DataExtensionCategoryID+"</td></tr>");
  }
  Write("</table>");
  


} 
catch(error) {
Write('Message: '+ error);
}
</script>

There is some script that I can use?
Thanks
Edel
